# Get 405/404 error when trying to send mails with Graph API (OAuth2 client credentials flow)

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, clientcredential

I'm making a Java application to send Mail as **any user** in a Microsoft tenant, with Graph APIs, so I'm using the **client credentials flow** (no login, automatic send).
I've registered an app in Azure AD giving the following **application permissions (not delegated)**, checking out the admin consent for every item:

- Mail.Send
- Mail.ReadWrite
- User.Read.All

For semplicity, I've tried also with calls in Postman, but I have the same issue as in the Java app. I take for granted that I have got a valid access token (If I try with an invalid one, I get a `401: Unauthorized`). The following is the decoded access token that I get from https://jwt.ms/, **with all the scopes included**:

```
...
  "roles": [
    "Mail.ReadWrite",
    "User.Read.All",
    "Mail.Send"
  ],
...
```

This is my code in Java:

```
String user = "/users/<my user id or my user principal name>";
    
    UserRequestBuilder defaultUser = new UserRequestBuilder(graphClient.getServiceRoot() + user, graphClient, null);
    
    //graphClient.me()
    defaultUser
        .sendMail(UserSendMailParameterSet
            .newBuilder()
            .withMessage(message)
            .withSaveToSentItems(saveToSentItems)
            .build())
        .buildRequest()
        .post();
```

I can't use the "me" target (`me()` method) because this is client credentials flow, so there isn't a logged user. I need to specify the sender in this way: `/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/sendMail`.

This is how the call in Postman is composed:

Method: POST

URL:

- .https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/`{my user id or my user principal name}`/sendMail

AUTHORIZATION:

- Bearer Token (my access token)

HEADERS:

- Content-Type: application/json

BODY(JSON):

```
{
    "recipient":    <recipient email>,
    "subject":      "This is a test mail",
    "from":         <mail that created the tenant, app and access token>,
    "text":         "This is the messge body..."
}
```

That's the response from the server (in both Postman and Java app):

STATUS: **405: Method Not Allowed**

BODY:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "Specified HTTP method is not allowed for the request target.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-08-05T07:17:34",
            "request-id": "XXXXXXXX-6075-4d13-83ed-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "client-request-id": "XXXXXXXX-6075-4d13-83ed-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
        }
    }
}
```

**Note 1:**
I got my user id and my user principal name also with a Postman call using my access token,
exploiting the `User.Read.All` permission, with the following call:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

That's the response:

```
...
            "userPrincipalName": "XXXXXX_XXXXXX.XXX#EXT#@sendClientCredMail.onmicrosoft.com",
            "id": "XXXXXXXX-4457-4944-bb22-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Note 2:**
Note that if I use the "principal name" in the call, I get a 405, if I use the "id" instead I get a **404: Not Found**

Thanks in advance for any help, I've been trying for hours!

Comment: Are you sure that this user has an active mailbox?

Comment: Can you please share the query details client request id and timestamp

Comment: @bisi did you got answer to your question.I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

##### SOLVED

As Optimal said in the comments, the issue was that the user didn't have a licensed mailbox.
When I assigned a "Microsoft 365 Business Premium" license to that user, my code worked fine.
Check the licenses both on portal.azure.com for assignments, and on admin.microsoft.com for the active mailbox

Kind regards